# Make DIV tag of equal width in same horizental row?

Tags: html, css

```
getting both tag on same row but there size are not equal...
```

i want to make both div tag "Add More Item" and "Remove Item" of ewual width on same line...

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all" style="margin: 20px; width: auto">

            <div class="ui-btn ui-first-child"   style="   position: relative;  center; background-color: #36CD5A; color: #fff; text-shadow: none !important;"  data-inline="true" onclick="javascript:addNewItem()">Add More Item</div>

            <div class="ui-btn ui-last-child"  style="  position: relative; text-align: center; background-color: #36CD5A; color: #fff; text-shadow: none !important;"  onclick="javascript:removeAddedItem()">Remove Item</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: There are to many ways, do it need to be responsive ? is it a fixed width ? etc... more details and will be happy to help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all" style="margin: 20px; width: auto;background-color:#36CD5A;">

    <div class="ui-btn ui-first-child" style="   position: relative;  center; color: #fff; text-shadow: none !important;display: inline;" data-inline="true" onclick="">Add More Item</div> |

    <div class="ui-btn ui-last-child" style="  position: relative; text-align: center;color: #fff; text-shadow: none !important;display: inline;" onclick="">Remove Item</div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hd6mzs0x/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `width:50%` and `float:left`, below is the code

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all" style="margin: 20px; width: auto">
  <div class="ui-btn ui-first-child"   style="text-align:center; background-color: #36CD5A; width:50%;float:left"  data-inline="true" onclick="javascript:addNewItem()">Add More Item</div> 
  <div class="ui-btn ui-last-child"  style="text-align: center; background-color: yellow; width:50%;float:left"  onclick="javascript:removeAddedItem()">Remove Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs , here float will make div to sit next to other. You can also use display:inline-block

Comment: Kumar i'm not following this anymore..  avoid float is a good tip..

do you understand what the difference is between inline, inline-block and block-level elements ??

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs  yes I know differences among inline, inline-block and block-level elements, that is why I mention there

Comment: Kumar , sorry .. confused, give me a moment

Comment: Kumar yes you did mention, just avoid float for layout use float for text wrapping tecs  https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs Check in https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ link, they have also used float's for layout

Answer (score 0):

You can make via table or css pseudo property. here is full expanded examples. Have a look https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

***All examples are examples don't copy&paste.***

*Example inline block, responsive, nth-child (range)*

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  outline: 1px green solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: solid yellow;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(-n+2) {
  background-color: green;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+4) {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper > div:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(-n+6) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    i love red
  </div>
  <div>
    i love pink
  </div>
  <div>
    i love green
  </div>
  <div>
    i love creeps
  </div>
  <div>
    i love green
  </div>
  <div>
    i love purple
  </div>
</div>
```

*Example flex*

```css
.wrapper2 {
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrapper2 > div {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2">
  <div>
    i love red
  </div>
  <div>
    i love pink
  </div>
  <div>
    i love green
  </div>
  <div>
    i love creeps
  </div>
  <div>
    i love green
  </div>
  <div>
    i love purple
  </div>
</div>
```

There are so many ways to do what you ask, so provide more  details so we can help you better.